# Why does socket connection not work inside onsubmit-event?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Spent a good while wondering why the connection to websocket ("var..." and  "socket.on..." statements) do not work when placed inside the function that follows onsubmit:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        document.querySelector('#display_name').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('display_name');

        document.querySelector('#new_channel').onsubmit = () => {

          const new_channel_name = document.querySelector('#new_channel_name').value;
          console.log(`New channel name: ${new_channel_name}`);


          var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
          socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log("THIS NEVER GETS EXECUTED");
          }); 

       };
   });
```

When moving the connection statements out, the connection seems to work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        document.querySelector('#display_name').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('display_name');

        var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log(`Connected to SOCKET ID: ${socket.id}`);
            });

        document.querySelector('#new_channel').onsubmit = () => {

          const new_channel_name = document.querySelector('#new_channel_name').value;
          console.log(`New channel name: ${new_channel_name}`);

          };
      });
```

Looks like a fundamental lack of understanding something here on my side, but no luck finding explanations as to why... Anyone can help me understand why?

Ultimately my goal is to make a chat app using multiple channels or namespaces (with a Flask server using SocketIO), hence my desire to only create the connection once a user **submits** the new channel form, and not before when the client does not know what path/channel to connect to. And I know that I will have to change the socket-initialization to include some path to the non-default channel (so far I am simply trying to get it to connect). Anyone know how to get around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer noted, you need to call `event.preventDefault()` in order to prevent the page from reloading.

Another issue is you're trying to connect each time the submit button is clicked, but you don't send any parameter to the server that indicates the channel, so it's best to send the correct channel name to the server.

So, the best solution is:

- add `e.preventDefault()`
- store sockets in a `sockets` global variable, and `push` to it whenever there is a new connection along with the channel name
- send channel name to the server
- if there is a connection request, first check if that channel name exists in `sockets`

Comment: spent some time on this and turns out indeed that connecting to a new socket and new socket-id (i.e. different socket-id) each time is not the way to go. Needed to connect ONCE and then use separate `room`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the submit event fired by a form, you may need to prevent default to keep the page from reloading? A page reload would end your socket connection.

https://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/submitting-html-form-without-reload-the-page/

```
x.onsubmit = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); more code}
```